# Searching DataGridView without changing the DataGridView Table

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` with some data. I also have a search `TextBox` and when its text changes, I want to search in the `DataGridView` without *changing* the data in the original `DataGridView`.

When the client writes his search line, the `DataGridView` would do one of those options:

1. Show only the line that matches the search line,
2. or will jump the client to the row and highlight it (better than 1).

While searching on StackOverflow I could find similar cases but could not apply any of their solutions in my program.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
        string.Format("name = '{0}'", search.Text);
}
```

But it's only showing an empty `DataGridView` although I should have an outcome.

---

I added to my Fund class function that search for all the names in the list:

```
public static List<Fund> findFundbyName(string name)
{
    return funds.Where(c => c.name.Contains(name)).ToList();
}
```

then when updating the `DataGridView` I used this function:

```
if (search.Text != "")
{
    table = ConvertListToTable(Fund.funds, search.Text);
}
else
{
    table = ConvertListToTable(Fund.funds, "");
}
```

Comment: Why exactly does it not work as expected? Do you get any error?

Comment: No i dont get any error, it's just showing empty datagrideview although i sould have an outcome.

Comment: How have you initialized the `Datasource` property?

Comment: What do yu mean?

Comment: This: `string.Format("name = '{0}'", search.Text);` tries to filter using an exact match. If no match is found, the result is an empty DataView. Maybe you want something like `string.Format("name LIKE '%{0}%'", search.Text);` (a partial match). The filter is generated in a TextChanged event, so...